# Python Shelve Module Memory Consumption

Tags: python, code-readability, shelve, tradeoff, performance

I have been assigned the task of reading a .txt file which is a log of various events and writing some of those events into a dictionary.

The problem is that the file can sometimes get bigger than 3GB in size. This means that the dictionary gets too big to fit into main memory. It seems that [Shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html#shelve-example) is a good way to solve this problem. However, since I will be constantly modifying the dictionary, I must have the `writeback` option enabled. This is where I am concerned - the tutorial says that this would slow down the read/write process and use more memory, but I am unable to find statistics on how the speed and memory are affected.

Can anyone clarify by how much the read/write speed and memory are affected so that I can decide whether to use the writeback option or sacrifice some readability for code efficiency?

Thank you

Comment: It depends what you're doing with the dictionary: if you only need to modify it by replacing values (`shelf['key'] = newvalue`), you don't need writeback. If you're modifying mutable types in it (`shelf['key'].append(x)`, you need writeback. Of course, you can leave writeback off and always remember to modify and replace values in your shelf, if you prefer.

Comment: I only need to add key, value pairs. But since I'm working with nested dictionaries, I will be adding k,v pairs to the inner dicts as well.

Comment: Can you write it so that you always grab a value from the shelf, add to that at whatever level, and then put it back on the shelf?

Comment: Would that be the way show in the tutorial that uses the `temp` variable

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid doing, though. I can do it if I have tom, but I'd like to avoid it as much as possible - hence the whole writeback issue. Thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at the source code: http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/shelve.py?view=markup In short, it will store everything you touch in memory until you call `.sync()`, at which point it's rewritten to disk and freed. So the hit depends on what sort of pattern you're accessing the file in.

Comment: I know that this doesn't answer your question, but for data on that scale it may be worth looking into another embedded document store. Maybe unqlite?

Answer (score 2):

For databases this size, shelve really is the wrong tool. If you do not need a *highly available* client/server architecture, and you just want to convert your TXT file to a local in-memory-accessible database, you really should be using [ZODB](http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/ZODB)

If you need something highly-available, you will of course need to switch to a formal "NoSQL" database, of which there are many to choose from.

Here's a simple example of how to convert your shelve database to a ZODB database which will solve your memory usage / performance problems.

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shelve
import ZODB, ZODB.FileStorage
import transaction
from optparse import OptionParser
import os
import sys
import re

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

parser = OptionParser()

parser.add_option("-o", "--output", dest = "out_file", default = False, help ="original shelve database filename")
parser.add_option("-i", "--input", dest = "in_file", default = False, help ="new zodb database filename")

parser.set_defaults()
options, args = parser.parse_args()

if options.in_file == False or options.out_file == False :
    print "Need input and output database filenames"
    exit(1)

db = shelve.open(options.in_file, writeback=True)
zstorage = ZODB.FileStorage.FileStorage(options.out_file)
zdb = ZODB.DB(zstorage)
zconnection = zdb.open()
newdb = zconnection.root()

for key, value in db.iteritems() :
    print "Copying key: " + str(key)
    newdb[key] = value
                                                                                                                                                                                                
transaction.commit()
```